# SQL SELECT Statement for nested Selects

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I am having problems formulating a SQL select statement. Here's the problem.
I have 3 tables:

```
Project (projId, projName)
User (userId, userName)
projUser (projId, userId, isOwner)
```

The idea is a user can either be an owner of a project or a participant.

I want to write a select statement where I can pass in a userId and return all the projects that the user is either an owner of or a participant of. But in the result I want an "owner" column that lists the owner of the project of which this user is a participant of or an owner of. For instance.
Assuming we have passed the userid for the user "Bob", the result should look something like this:

User table:

```
userId  Name
1       Bob
2       Sean 
3       Jim
```

projUser table:

```
projId    userId   isOwner
1         1          1
2         2          1
2         1          0
3         1          1
4         3          1
3         3          0
```

Result:

```
projId  projName isOwner Owner
1       project1   1     Bob
2       project2   0     Sean
3       project3   1     Bob
```

Comment: You should add a `UNIQUE INDEX` to your database to prevent multiple `projUser` rows allowing multiple users to own the same project.

Comment: So can a project have multiple owners? Sounds like you assume it cannot but, as already noted, your schema certainly supports that.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @userId int = ( SELECT userId FROM user WHERE [name] = 'Bob' );

SELECT
    pu.projId,
    p.projName,
    pu.isOwner,
    ISNULL( ou.[name], '(No owner)' ) AS OwnerUserName
FROM
    projUser AS pu
    INNER      JOIN project  AS p  ON pu.projId = p.projId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN projUser AS po ON p.projId  = pu.projId AND po.isOwner = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN projUser AS ou ON ou.userId = po.userId
WHERE
    pu.userId = @userId
```

Comment: what's ou? the compiler complains about "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'" on this line: LEFT OUTER JOIN          AS ou ON ou.userId = po.userId

Comment: @SeanD Sorry, I typo’d. I’ve now corrected my answer.

Comment: I think you still have a typo in your query since ou.name is invalid. Looking at the tables above, you haven't done a join on the USER table to get the name of the user. if I remove the ISNULL(.....) line and execute the query as is I get the following: ProjId: 25  ProjNameD2 IsOwner: 0 result repeating even though there are other projects